# Did the kerning/leading just change on SE?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, design

It's very slight, but I just ran through all my SE tabs in Safari refreshing one after the other, as I do a hundred times a day [when I'm bored] & everything on each page just spaced a tiny bit wider.

It's probably not easy to see until you fullscreen this [snaps are from a 27" 1440p screen] but *something* just changed on every refreshed page.  After a few of these I realised I should grab a screen snap of a before & after - you'll have to open each in a new window & flick between to see the effect; it is very slight.

Before:

[image: picture beforehand]

After:

[image: screenshot afterwards, slightly wider]

<sup>medium images inlined, click to open full size in new window. imgur's 'medium' tag  is what puts the bad black 'transparency' around the 'm' pictures in here.</sup>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I recently changed how some of our variables are passed around, simplifying things and making sure our `body` and `html` elements inherit from a single place instead of a super circuitous route. Something may have shifted slightly.

Comment: OK, thanks. Good to know. It was one of those 'blink & you miss it' moments, but it seemed too consistent to be 'random'.

Comment: I think I remember that "circuitous route" 

Comment: @balpha. It's always balpha. :-D

Comment: @balpha I deleted the variables coming from `base-primary` and now it just comes from `stacks-base`. Let's hope the website still works 